# Android canvas get real Pixelresolution

Tags: android, pixel, android-canvas

With canvas.getWidth() and canvas.getHeight() I get a Resolution of 320x533, but my Device has 480x800. There is a divisor of 1.5 in it. When I do some drawings on the canvas there is the same.

Can I change this behaivior? I need the real resolution of a device and need exact painting without using float values.

Answer (score 1):

Add target in your AndroidManifest >= 4. In Android 1.5, you have only 480*320.

Try this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<supports-screens
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:resizeable="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Thx, I understand. But that means I will not target the Android 1.5 devices.

Comment: Look this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html But nobody have 1.5 phones!